# Your project should have a settings.gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, gitlab

Hi I'm try to build a flutter app on git lab and every time its fails and show me the Error below:

> Executing Gradle tasks as part of a build without a settings file
> is not supported. Make sure that you are executing Gradle from a
> directory within your Gradle project. Your project should have a
> 'settings.gradle(.kts)' file in the root directory.

I changed the location of the file setting.gradle and not work

any help??

[the root of gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaOIm.png)

Comment: Can you please include some information on your current project structure (where is your build.gradle, your settins.gradle, etc) so we can see how you have it set up currently?

Comment: @patrick 
please check the update

Comment: Ok, so you have a multi-project build (nested build.gradle files). This requires special syntax in your gradle and settings files - can you please include the contents of those files as well? Preferably as code blocks instead of as images :)

Answer (score 1):

After searching and going through various trial and error methods, I finally tried the `gradle init` command  and it fixed the issue. Alththough the `settings.gradle` file was already present but somehow its not seen by gradle  itself, and initializing gradle fixed the error for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).